# Does php FLOCK work on load balanced web servers?

Tags: php, stingray

We are upgrading from a single web server to 3 load balanced web servers using Stingray and Linux OS. We currently use PHP FLOCK to access a file which provides a unique sequence number to web page requests. Does FLOCK still work with load balanced servers or will we have to put that logic in mySQL to provide exclusive locking?

Comment: Is the file available to all servers (the same file and not copies of the file)?  It would make sense (IMHO) to move this logic to the database though.

Comment: Yes, there is only one file - not 3 copies of it. Each time any server requests a unique number the file is updated.